# Is there a way to run a docker image automatically on an EC2 instance?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance containing a docker image. I would like the docker image in the EC2 instance to automatically run whenever the EC2 instance is turned on. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are trying to run a container in a VM instead of Elastic Container Service (ECS)?

Comment: I am a new AWS user so I don't know much about ECS but I yes I have now seen that people use ECS for docker containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly don't know if the is an 'AWS' way of doing so,
but you can actually create a simple bash script, that runs the EC2 instance and set all your requirements.

Honestly, working with ECS makes more sense than creating a vm and on tom of him a docker container.

```bash
# install jq
apt install jq -y

instanceName=your_vm_name

# Get the vm ID and state.
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters "Name=tag:Name, Values=$instanceName" \
    "Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped" \
    --query "Reservations[].Instances[0]" > vm.json

# extract the vm ID from the output json from AWS.
instanceId=$(cat vm.json | jq '.[].InstanceId')

# Start your vm.
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids $instanceId

# Use SSH to remotely execute your docker script.

sudo ssh -i your_key_pair_pem_file user@vm_im 'docker run -p port:port --name container_name image_name'
```

That way you will not have to get into the VM and executing commands in to it.